# Is there a pythonic way in unwrapping list for the following example?

Tags: python

For example:

```
list1=['a','b']
list2 = [['apple', 'pineapple'], ['orange', 'grapes']]
```

I want to get something like:

```
[ ['a', 'apple'], ['a', 'pineapple'], ['b', 'orange'],, ['b', 'grapes'] ]
```

I tried `[[i1, i2] for i1, i2 in itertools.izip(list1, list2)]` but this will give me the following:

```
[ ['a',['apple', 'pineapple'], ['b', ['orange', 'grapes']] ]
```

I know why it is wrong as i2 is an element of list type but I do not know how to solve this in a more pythonic way after several failed attempts. I can definitely iterate row by row and use for loop and  `append()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a nested comprehension to unwrap the inner list items:

```
>>> [[i, x] for i, j in zip(list1, list2) for x in j]
[['a', 'apple'], ['a', 'pineapple'], ['b', 'orange'], ['b', 'grapes']]
```

Answer (score 1):

without itertools

```
final = []
for i,k in enumerate(list1):
    for j in list2[i]:
        final.append([k,j])
print final

[['a', 'apple'], ['a', 'pineapple'], ['b', 'orange'], ['b', 'grapes']]
```

one liner:

```
[[k,j] for j in list2[i] for i,k in enumerate(list1)]
```

Comment: make it a one-liner as well ;-)

Comment: added.hope that helps.